# Discord.js : "Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role" while creating channel through button interaction

Tags: discord.js

The bot was working fine while making this. The error started popping from last week.

I don't understand what's wrong as I have also tried the same code on another bot and it creates channel fine.

I thought maybe it had to do with discord making the 19 character snowflake but that's not the case.

> **Here is the *index.js* file** (I have a omitted few things)
> *ID* is the member username who clicked the button.
> *staff1*, *staff2*, *everyone* roles are defined above. [ const staff1 = "role-id"; etc ]
> *verifyParent* is the ID of the category under which the channel is created. [ Defined above ]

```cpp
    switch (customId) {
      case 'VERIFY':
        await interaction.guild.channels.create(`${customId + "-" + ID}`, {
            type: "GUILD_TEXT",
            parent: verifyParent,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.member.id,
                allow: [ "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY" ]
              },
              {
                id: staff1,
                allow: [ "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY" ]
              },
              {
                id: staff2,
                allow: [ "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY" ]
              },
              {
                id: everyone,
                deny: [ "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY" ]
              }
            ]
        })
        .then(async(channel) => {
            channel.send(`${ID} Please send the details.`);
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    }
```

> **The error I got:**

```cpp
    TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.
    at PermissionOverwrites.resolve (/home/runner/cum-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/PermissionOverwrites.js:184:28)
    at /home/runner/cum-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildChannelManager.js:145:81
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GuildChannelManager.create (/home/runner/cum-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildChannelManager.js:145:51)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/cum-bot/index.js:120:48)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
        [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
    }
```

> I have looked at other posts and nothing works. I have tried to reset the bot token and still the same thing.
> The same code is working fine on a test bot of mine but not with this one.
> And no, the bot is not *rate limited*.

Thanks!

Comment: Which one is line 120?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `interaction.member.id` is the person who sent the interaction itself. if you are trying to get the person that pressed the button, i believe it is:

```
{
id: interaction.user.id,
allow: [ "SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNEL", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY" ]
}
```

Comment: Apparently that was the exact case. I'm stupid.
interaction.member also has an ID so I thought it would be the same thing.